# Getting Samba working in manjoro linux, daemon failed to start: Samba detected misconfigured 'server role' and exited.

Tags: systemd, samba, smb, samba4

I recently tried to start samba on manjoro linux.

```
systemctl start samba.service
systemctl status samba.service
● samba.service - Samba AD Daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/samba.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-04-21 10:40:03 SAST; 1s ago
 Process: 5913 ExecStart=/usr/bin/samba $SAMBAOPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5914 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 21 10:40:02 aaron-pc systemd[1]: Starting Samba AD Daemon...
Apr 21 10:40:02 aaron-pc systemd[1]: Started Samba AD Daemon.
Apr 21 10:40:03 aaron-pc systemd[1]: samba.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 10:40:03 aaron-pc systemd[1]: samba.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 21 10:40:03 aaron-pc systemd[1]: samba.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  

less /var/log/samba/%m.log 
.....
samba version 4.5.8 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2016
[2017/04/21 10:31:05.057860,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:466(binary_smbd_main)
At this time the 'samba' binary should only be used for either:
'server role = active directory domain controller' or to access the ntvfs file server with 'server services = +smb' or the rpc proxy with 'dcerpc endpoint servers = remote'
You should start smbd/nmbd/winbindd instead for domain member and standalone file server tasks
[2017/04/21 10:31:05.057905,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:111(exit_daemon)
STATUS=daemon failed to start: Samba detected misconfigured 'server role' and exited. Check logs for details, error code 22
....
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
testparm 
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Processing section "[Aaron-share]"
Processing section "[Aaron-movies]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
    server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbindd, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate, dns, smb
    server string = %h manjoro linux
    workgroup = ECN
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
    max log size = 1000
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    unix password sync = Yes
    dns proxy = No
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
```

Comment: I'm voting to keep this question open as I believe it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It was a misunderstanding on my part.

I don't need to start the samba.service.
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/
"[samba(8)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/samba.8.html)
Server to provide AD and SMB/CIFS services to clients"

```
systemctl disable samba
systemctl stop samba
```

What I actually need is the [smbd service](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Using_Samba_in_your_File_Manager).
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbd.8.html
"smbd — server to provide SMB/CIFS services to clients"

I don't need to run an AD type setup, I just want to share my files to other pcs.

```
systemctl enable smb
systemctl start smb
systemctl status smb
systemctl enable nmb
systemctl start nmb
systemctl status nmb
```

That should be enough to get a working share accessible provided your smb.conf has all the correct settings.

For more information you should read the arch docs
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/samba

I found this links helpful.
https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Using_Samba_in_your_File_Manager
https://forum.antergos.com/topic/5557/samba-won-t-start-can-t-share-folders-over-network/3

Comment: It would be best to mark this answer as *accepted* so that it appears as "answered".

Comment: on newer system, the services names are `smb` and `nmb`. also you need to install a package before you start these services `sudo pacman -S manjaro-settings-samba`

Comment: None of the above worked for me. For users like me, the following solved my issue:
run `testparm`
locate/fix any error
For me, it was the missing `security` parameters (defaulting to ADS). Adding this line fixed it ([global]):
`security = USER`